# Using .animate on scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How do I go by adding .animate to this piece of code?

```
$("body,html").scrollTop($("#wrapper3").position().top);
```

I have tried adding `.animate` before `scrollTop`, but it keeps showing an error in Dreamweaver.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<html lang="da">
<html>
<head>
<link href="_css/fddkStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="_jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>




<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="bar16"></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper2">
</div>

<div id="wrapper3">
</div>


<script src="_jquery/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="_jquery/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="_jquery/my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="_jquery/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#bar16").click(function() {
$("body,html").scrollTop($("#wrapper3").position().top);


});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what and how you want to achieve your result, but if I understood what you meant you can do:

```
<h1 id="anchor">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p><a href="#anchor" class="topLink">Back to Top</a></p>
```

And jQuery:

```
    $("a.topLink").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The #anchor can be changed to what you want and the "Back to Top" is going to go to your #anchor. Just make sure the div (or in this case h1) has an idenditcal id.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/3tgcp/1/)

***A POSSIBLE REASON for jumping to the top of the page is the fact you have NOT loaded jQuery. Make sure jQuery IS LOADED.***

***EDIT***

Ok after your edits you should just change this

```
<div id="bar16"></div>
```

to this

```
<div id="bar16">
    <a href="#wrapper3" class="topLink">CLICK HERE</a></div>
</div>
```

***Like here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/3tgcp/3/)***

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear. The code I inserted is being used to scroll the screen to a specific div, in this case #wrapper3. Right now it just jumps directly to the div without any animation, I would like it to animate the scroll with a smooth animation down to the div.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie to this so I am confused where I would insert the div tag where it should scroll to.

Comment: Edit your first question posting your HTML so I can see it.

Comment: It is working like it should, I just want to add animation to this piece of code. $("body,html").scrollTop($("#wrapper3").position().top); Can I do that by adding .animate before scrollTop and if yes, how would the precise way of doing it be?

Comment: OK, than please be specific. WHAT animation? It's already implemented with .animation, just add whatever you want there.

Comment: If I want to add .animate and easing swing to this code $("body,html").scrollTop($("#wrapper3").position().top);  Would it be something like this $("body,html").animate(scrollTop($("#wrapper3").position().top); ?

Comment: That did the trick :) Thank you very much. Too low on reputation so I can't even upvote your solution but thank you!

Comment: @user2559792 You are very welcome. You can't up-vote but press the TICK so that it's set as THE answer for the question.