# Live Scroll Issues (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a website right now and have run into an issue.  Im pretty new to all of this so im sure its a simply fix.  basically, i would like to use javascript to have an onlick event in which clicking a link in the header will result in a live animated scroll down to a point on the page.  The issue?  no live scroll, it just jumps.  heres a snippet of the code.  thanks!

```
<head style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <title>Dupont Studios</title>
    <link href= 'style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="waypoints.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script>


        $(function() {
        // Do our DOM lookups beforehand
        var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
        var nav = $("nav");
        nav_container.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
        nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');

        }
        });
        });

    </script>
    <script>
        $(".nav-item").on("click", function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("body, html").animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 600);

        });
    </script>
</head>

<div id = 'nav-items-container'>
            <ul class = 'nav-items'>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

example of a jump point:

```
 <div class = 'mark' id = 'how'></div>
```

another attempt at the js which doesnt work

```
 $("a.nav-item").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
        });
```

Comment: Today someone asked the same thing, see if this helps you: [Using .animate on scrollTop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521234/using-animate-on-scrolltop/)

Comment: i gave that a shot and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work out because you tried my answer from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521234/using-animate-on-scrolltop/) but you have a different setup.
So this will work:

```
$("li.nav-item").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The point is that the element you are looking for #tag is inside an A element inside the LI element. Ypu can see a ***[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHmbK/)***

**EDITED**

There are quite a few errors in your document, that's why is not working. When in trouble open FF or Chrome Dev Tools (Console...) so that you can see what's wrong. There is an error within  the code "waypoint" and can't load it. I commented it for now. The following works like a charm:

```
<html>
<head style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <title>Dupont Studios</title>
    <link href= 'style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function(){
            /*Do our DOM lookups beforehand
            var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
            var nav = $("nav");
            nav_container.waypoint({
                handler: function(direction) {
                    nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');
                }
            });*/


            $("li.nav-item").click(function() {
                alert("ok");
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .long_div{
            background-color: lightblue;
            min-height: 600px; 
            border: thin solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = 'nav-items-container'>
            <ul class = 'nav-items'>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
                <li class = 'nav-item'><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="what" class="long_div">
            What
        </div>
        <div id="how" class="long_div">
            How
        </div>
        <div id="why" class="long_div">
            Why
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i replaced the above code with the stuff I had and it's still not working.  the fiddle works great tho so im confused.  any ideas?  thanks for the help btw